# How to compare various NSArrays in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

My code contains four `NSArray`s, each of which contains two objects which represent XY-Coordinate at any point on the screen. Two or more arrays may contain same set of coordinates. I need to find the coordinate which has highest number of repetition among these four arrays. Can the `isEqualTo:` method help in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to maintain an `NSDictionary`, use the coordinates in your arrays as keys and then maintain a counter for each coordinate (i.e. key) that you increment whenever you see the same coordinate.

This could look somewhat like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *coordinateCount = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) { // do this loop for each of your 4 arrays
   Coordinate *c = coordinates[i];
   if ([coordinateCount containsKey:c]) {
      NSInteger count = [coordinateCount[c] integerValue];
      count++;
      coordinateCount[c] = @(count);
   }
   else {
      coordinateCount[c] = @(1);
   }
}

// now you can retrieve the max count value from all collected values
```

Note that this code is not tested and has to be adjusted depending on your types and variable names.

Comment: An [`NSCountedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/) can achieve the same thing in much less code, e.g. `NSCountedSet *coordinateCount = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:coordinates]`.

Comment: oh nice, yeah `NSCountedSet` looks like a good alternative... at least you save the code for initializing the counts in the array

Comment: More precisely, in my algorithm, the four arrays predict any coordinate respectively and I need to decide a coordinate according to these predictions. For Eg: When all the arrays or at least three of them contain same coordinate then I can return this array. However, if  first two arrays predict one coordinate and last two predict  next coordinate then I am supposed to return average of X part and Y part of coordinate respectively. How can I solve it using objective C? @nburk